# Highlight a # section in a page - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple html page

```
<html>
<div id="d1>Content</div>
<div id="d2>Content</div>
<div id="d3>Content</div>
<a href="page.html#d1">D1</a> <a href="page.html#d2">D2</a> <a href="page.html#d3">D3</a>
</html>
```

I want to highlight the selected div, with my script

```
<script>
var divID=window.location.href.split('#')[1];
$(divID).blahblahEffect;
<script>
```

The problem is this works only the first time when i moved from X page to page.html, after going to page.html if i click on any Links it does not show the effect.

Comment: You can use `window.location.hash` to get the hash.

Comment: read this : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

#### CSS

```
.highlight{ background-color :#FCFC9F; }
```

#### jQuery

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
   $('div').removeClass('highlight');
   var hashId=this.hash.substr(1);
   $('#'+hashId).addClass('highlight');           
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xRXn7/1/)

Comment: I'm astounded this works - does a DOM element have a `hash` property as well? This can come in handy. It looks like it is a hidden feature because I cannot seem to find anything on this on the Internet. Thanks!

Comment: @pimvdb actually this is also present in JavaScript `window.location.hash;`

Comment: I did know about `location.hash` but not that it was a property of an `<a>` element too.