# Highlight linked headline

Tags: jquery, css, highlight

How can I add a CSS-class "highlight" to headlines or sections based on anchors like "...this.html#headline1" (e.g. the TOCs on Wikipedia).

This should also work when coming from a different page (href="http://mysite.com/this.html#headline1") and NOT only onclick like here: [Highlight a # section in a page - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945751/highlight-a-section-in-a-page-jquery)

Comment: simply use the same code (i.e. `var hashId=this.hash.substr(1);`) wrapped in an `onload` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer browsers, you can make use of the [CSS3 `:target` pseudo selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo).

```css
*:target {
     background-color: #F5FFE1;
}
```

[**This does not work in IE 8 and below and not correctly in Opera**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t316).

Comment: @Martin: Well, it comes with the drawbacks that it won't work in all browsers. If this is a problem for you, you have to fall back to JavaScript. But anyways: You're welcome :)

Comment: Browser incompability for CSS3: That's the user's fault for using a crap browser then. I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `window.location.hash` and highlight that `id`, assuming your page is structured that way.

### CSS

```
.highlight{ background-color :#FCFC9F; }
```

### jQuery

```
function highlight() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;

  if(hash) {
    $(hash).addClass('highlight');
  }
}

highlight(); // Do this on page load

$('a').on('click', highlight); // Do this on every `a` click
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of jQuery, but the CSS3 solution is more elegant and stable

Comment: Stable how? It's not cross-browser, as Felix indicated.

Comment: CSS solutions are more stable than JS solutions in general.